# Подключение стилей через link в Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack5

Мне нужно настроить вебпак конфиг так, чтобы стили подключались через link, а не инлайново через style.

Стили я подключаю через js файл так

```
import './style.scss'
import '../assets/scss/datepicker.min.scss'
```

Мой webpack.config Версия webpack 5

```
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const isProd = !isDev;
const filename = (ext) => isDev ? `[name].${ext}` : `[name].[contenthash].${ext}`;

module.exports = () => {

    const PATHS = {
        src: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
        dist: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    };

    const PAGES_DIR = `${PATHS.src}/pages/`;

    return {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: {
            index: [`${PAGES_DIR}/index.js`],
            'search-room': [`${PAGES_DIR}/website-pages/search-room/index.js`],
            'room_details': [`${PAGES_DIR}/website-pages/room-details/index.js`],
            'login': [`${PAGES_DIR}/website-pages/login/index.js`],
            'registration': [`${PAGES_DIR}/website-pages/registration/index.js`],
            'site-pages': [`${PAGES_DIR}/ui-kit/index.js`],
            'cards': [`${PAGES_DIR}/ui-kit/cards/index.js`],
            'colors-type': [`${PAGES_DIR}/ui-kit/colors-type/index.js`],
            'elements': [`${PAGES_DIR}/ui-kit/elements/index.js`],
            'header-footer': [`${PAGES_DIR}/ui-kit/header-footer/index.js`],
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'js/[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist')
        },
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
            contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            open: true,
            compress: true,
            hot: true,
            port: 3000,
        },
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/,
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
              }),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                  {
                    from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
                    to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets'),
                  },
                ],
              }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/index.pug`,
                filename: './index.html',
                chunks: ['index']
            }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/website-pages/search-room/searchRoom.pug`,
                filename: './searchRoom.html',
                chunks: ['search-room']
            }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/website-pages/room-details/roomDetails.pug`,
                filename: './roomDetails.html',
                chunks: ['room_details']
            }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/website-pages/login/login.pug`,
                filename: './login.html',
                chunks: ['login']
            }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/website-pages/registration/Registration.pug`,
                filename: './Registration.html',
                chunks: ['registration']
            }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/ui-kit/site-pages.pug`,
                filename: './ui-kit/site-pages.html',
                chunks: ['site-pages']
            }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/ui-kit/cards/cards.pug`,
                filename: './ui-kit/cards.html',
                chunks: ['cards']
            }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/ui-kit/colors-type/colors-type.pug`,
                filename: './ui-kit/colors-type.html',
                chunks: ['colors-type']
            }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/ui-kit/elements/elements.pug`,
                filename: './ui-kit/elements.html',
                chunks: ['elements']
            }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/ui-kit/header-footer/header-footer.pug`,
                filename: './ui-kit/header-footer.html',
                chunks: ['header-footer']
            }),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: ('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
            }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    {
                      from: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/image'),
                      to:   path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/assets/image')
                    }
                  ]
                }),
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader',
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test:/\.(png|svg|jpg|svg|ico)$/,
                    type: 'asset/resource',
                    generator: {
                        filename: () => {
                            return isDev ? 'assets/image/[name].[contenthash][ext]' : 'assets/image/[name][ext]';
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(gif|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                    type: 'asset/resource',
                    generator: {
                        filename: () => {
                            return isDev ? 'assets/fonts/[name].[contenthash][ext]' : 'assets/fonts/[name][ext]';
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test:/\.pug$/,
                    use: ['pug-loader'],
                }
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать такой метод подключения стилей

```
{
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
},
```